# OSM only label internal boundaries with Carto and Mapnik

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, tilemill, cartocss, boundaries

Using the OSM workflow on switch2osm.org, we want to label all internal country boundaries but not external ones (coastlines).

There are 3 ways we could think of:

1. Is there any way to not show labels on polygon sides that have no neighbour (single sided)?
   For example, instead of the usual OSM labelling:
   [image]

Show something like this (done in ArcGIS with Maplex option to not allow single sided boundary labelling):[image]

2. Using Carto, is there any way to position labels from one feature (e.g. boundary polygon) along another feature (e.g. internal boundary line)?
3. Use text-comp-op in Carto to only display the (non-existing) coastline label and ignore the lower level admin boundaries?

Or are there any other methods out there?